# Performing Sum() Operation in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

i have table contain numeric fields and I want sum of the numeric field column using LINQ

Comment: What does your table look like?

Answer (score 3):

from [101 Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747#sumSimple):

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };

double numSum = numbers.Sum();
```

or..

```
string[] words = { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry" };

double totalChars = words.Sum(w => w.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not many details in your question, but something like this should work (if the table is supposed to be a database table, and you have generated the data context):

```
var sum = myDataContext.MyTable.Sum( v => v.MyColumnToSum );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "table" is a DataTable and "field" the numeric field, it is possibile to do like this:

```
sum = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.IsNull("field") ? 0.0 : (Double)row["field"]);
```

Here I used Double as numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim numbers() As Integer = {5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0}

Dim numSum = numbers.Sum()
```

This is vb, try to convert in c# or as your specific language.